# Jquery set how to set a global variable json post

Tags: jquery, variables, post, callback

Giving the following example:

```
var animal= null;

$.post("ajax.php",{data: data}, function(output){
     animal = output.animal;
},"json");

alert(animal);
```

In principle I wanted the variable to return something outside the ajax function's success callback and I declare it outside the post. However it is still returning "null". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is `asynchronous`...use callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the alert command is executing before the success function, because $.post is by definition asynchronous.

To do what you want, you have to use a synchronous request (the code will not execute before the request is over)  like this:

```
 var animal = null;

 $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        async: false,   // this is the important line that makes the request sincronous
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(output) {
                animal = output.animal;
             }
          );

  alert(animal);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

As `$.post()` is asynchronous. So you can't do what you want. Instead of that you have to use callback function like below:

```
var animal= null;

$.post("ajax.php",{data: data}, function(data){

     // this callback will execute after
     // after finish the post with
     // and get returned data from server

     animal = data.animal;
     callFunc(animal);
},"json");

function callFunc(animal) {
  alert(animal);
}
```